# Issue pushing new set of values to ordered list. - Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, list

I am trying to create a list taking in values and adding to that list on a button press (essentially adding products). It seems I am implementing the functionality incorrectly.

**CMP**

```
<aura:component controller="AddProductsController"
implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId"
access="global">
<aura:attribute name="productList"  type="List"/>
```

On button click it initiates this function within the controller:

**Controller**

```
handleProduct: function(cmp, evt){
    var ProductName = cmp.find("productType").get("v.value"); 
    var MID = cmp.get("v.selectedRecord.Name");
    var cardType = cmp.get("v.cardType");
    var PL = cmp.get("v.productList");
    var List = ([
        {MID: MID, CardType: cardType, Product: ProductName}
    ]);
    //PL.push(List);

    cmp.set("v.options", ProductName);
    //PL.push(MID);
    //PL.push(ProductName);
    //PL.push(cardType);
    cmp.set("v.productList",List);
},
```

Essentially what I want to do is push a new line to the list undernearh

```
{MID: MID, CardType: cardType, Product: ProductName}
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong.

**FULL Code: CMP**

```
<aura:component controller="AddProductsController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="opportunity" type="Opportunity"/>
<aura:attribute name="CNP" type="PricebookEntry[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="oppId" type="String" default="{!v.recordId}"/>
<aura:attribute name="cardType" type="String" default="No Type"/>
<aura:attribute name="productList"  type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="options" type="String" default="Nothing" />
<aura:attribute name="selectedRecord" type="Merchant_Account__c" default="{}" description="Use,for store SELECTED sObject Record"/>
<aura:attribute name="listOfSearchRecords" type="Merchant_Account__c[]" description="Use,for store the list of search records which returns from apex class"/>
<aura:attribute name="SearchKeyWord" type="string"/>
<aura:attribute name="showHome" type="Boolean" default="true" />
<aura:attribute name="Message" type="String" default="Search Result.."/>
<aura:attribute name="showCP" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="showCNP" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="showECOM" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <!--declare events hendlers-->  
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/> 
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.cardType}" action="{!c.handleValueChange}"/>
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.options}" action="{!c.handleSelect}"/>
<aura:handler name="add" value="{!v.productList}" action="{!c.handleProduct}"/>
<aura:handler name="next" value="{!v.showCP}" action="{!c.handleNext}"/>
<aura:handler name="oSelectedAccountEvent" event="c:selectedAccountEvent" action="{!c.handleComponentEvent}"/>
<aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.showSpinner}"/>
<aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.hideSpinner}"/>  

<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.SLDS24 + '/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css'}"/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showHome}">
        <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">SELECT A CARD TYPE</h3>

    <br></br>
    <fieldset class="slds-form--compound">
    <!-- Look up Component -->


        <!-- https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/lookups/ --> 
          <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-2">
      <div aura:id="searchRes" class="slds-form-element slds-lookup slds-is-close" data-select="single">
         <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="lookup-348"> Merchant Account Name </label>
         <!--This part is for display search bar for lookup-->  
         <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
               <c:svg class="slds-input__icon slds-show" xlinkHref="{!$Resource.SLDS24 + '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search'}" />
               <!-- This markup is for when an record is selected -->
               <div aura:id="lookup-pill" class="slds-pill-container slds-hide">
                  <span class="slds-pill">
                     <span class="slds-pill__label">
                       {!v.selectedRecord.Name}  
                     </span>
                     <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon slds-pill__remove" onclick="{!c.clear}">
                         <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" variant="bare" onclick="{!c.clear}" alternativeText="Close window." />
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Remove</span>
                     </button>
                  </span>
               </div>
              <div aura:id="lookupField" class="slds-show">
               <ui:inputText updateOn="keyup" keyup="{!c.keyPressController}" class="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input " value="{!v.SearchKeyWord}" placeholder="search.."/>
              </div>   
            </div>
         </div>
         <!--This part is for Display typehead lookup result List-->  
         <div class="slds-lookup__menu slds" id="lookup-348">
            <div class="slds-lookup__item--label slds-text-body--small">{!v.Message}</div>
            <center> <ui:spinner aura:id="spinner"/> </center>
            <ul class="slds-lookup__list" role="listbox">
               <aura:iteration items="{!v.listOfSearchRecords}" var="singleRec">
                  <c:customLookupResult oAccount="{!singleRec}" />
               </aura:iteration>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
        </div>
        <BR></BR>
        <div class="slds-form-element__group">
      <!-- CONSUMER DEBIT -->
      <div class="slds-form-element__row">
          <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-2">
              <ui:button label="Card Not Present" press="{!c.AddCNP}"/>
              <ui:button label="Card Present" press="{!c.AddCP}"/>
              <ui:button label="Ecommerce" press="{!c.AddECOM}"/></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <!-- END -->

    <div class="align-right">
              <lightning:buttonicon iconName="utility:add" size="medium" alternativeText="Add" onclick="{!c.handleMID}"/>
          </div>
    <h1>{!v.selectedRecord.Id} Selected</h1>
    <h1>{!v.cardType} Selected</h1>

    <br></br>
    <fieldset class="slds-form--compound">

        <div class="form-element__group">
          <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">Product Information</h3>   
          <div class="slds-form-element__row"/>        
          <div class="slds-form-element__row">
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-2">
        <ui:inputSelect class="slds-select" aura:id="lob" change="{!c.handleSelect}">
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="--Select Product--" value="0"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Terminal" value="1"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Gateway" value="2"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Other" value="3" /> 
            </ui:inputSelect>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-2">
              <ui:inputSelect class="slds-select" aura:id="productType">
                  <ui:inputSelectOption text="--Select Product--" value="0"/>
                </ui:inputSelect>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="align-right">
              <lightning:buttonicon iconName="utility:add" size="medium" alternativeText="Add" onclick="{!c.handleProduct}"/>
          </div>
          <h1>{!v.options} Added</h1>
            Added Products:
           <aura:iteration var="Plist" items="{!v.productList}">
               {!Plist}
            </aura:iteration>
            <ul></ul>
            <lightning:buttonicon iconName="utility:forward" size="medium" alternativeText="Next" onclick="{!c.handleNext}"/>
          <div class="slds-form-element__row"/>   
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      </aura:if>
```

Comment: Can you share more code how the things are linked/calling the functions?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 added full component code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a new item to the List first add that item to the existing List and then update the attribute with the updated List items:

**Component Controller**

```
handleProduct: function(cmp, evt){
    var ProductName = cmp.find("productType").get("v.value"); 
    var MID = cmp.get("v.selectedRecord.Name");
    var cardType = cmp.get("v.cardType");
    var PL = cmp.get("v.productList");

    /* Creating the new product to add to the list. */
    var product = {
        MID: MID,
        CardType: cardType,
        Product: ProductName}; 
    /* Pushed the new product to the list to update the main list  */
    PL.push(product);

    cmp.set("v.options", ProductName);

    /* Updating the product list with new product. */
    cmp.set("v.productList", PL); 
},
```

And in the component access the product list properties(MID, CardType, Product) like this:

**Component**

```
<aura:iteration var="product" items="{!v.productList}">
    <div>MID: {!product.MID}</div>
    <div>Card Type: {!product.CardType}</div>
    <div>Product: {!product.Product}</div>
</aura:iteration>
```